# How do I edit a numpy array with a variable? (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, variable-assignment

I am programming in python and have a large 2-D numpy array that I need to change a specific value of based on user input. Basically, the user input determines what location of the array needs to be modified, so I can't just reference it with a constant. I assigned the place that the user is trying to edit in the array (a) to variables (b,c). Then I used `a[b,c] = 1.0`, to assign the value I wanted but got the error:

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Also, the bits of the error message that are in code formatting (:, ..., and None) should have backticks around them, but Stack Overflow's formatting system turned them into code and I don't know how to fix that.

Edit: The b and c variables are both integers, and the dtype of the array is float. Sorry to The Photon for not making that clear. For additional context, I am programming this in Google Collab, and the array is the training data for a TensorFlow network. The array is all zeros except for the specific spots that I change into ones. "b" is an integer calculated using a function, while "c" is a value from another array that I manually input before running the code. The relevant parts of the code are this:

```
a = np.zeroes((6,144), dtype=float)
d = np.array([
    [25,55,28,63,30,71,39,27,34,45,5,31],
    [20,17,35,12,44,41,15,70,69,64,16,8],
    [60,43,62,49,9,14,62,49,18,29,51,59]], 
    dtype=float
)

n = 0
m = 0
while n < 3:
    while m < 12:
        c = d[n,m]
        a[b,c] = 1.0
        m += 1
    n += 1
```

The `a[b,c] = 1.0` is where the error is linked to.

Comment: What value did you have in the `b` and `c` variables? Was it an integer or was it a string or something else? Did you try converting it to integer before using it to index the array?

Comment: Sharing your actual code, or minimal example code that reproduces the problem, would help us to know this up front and be able to answer your question.

Comment: What do you mean the variables are integers?  Just that your user typed numbers?  Or that you tested the `type`, or did a `print`.   When programming, don't confuse your intentions with actuality.

Comment: @hpaulj That the user typed integers. I'm the only one who's going to be using this program, so it's fine if it breaks when someone puts in letters.

Comment: What's `b`?  `b=input()` or `b=int(input())`?

Comment: @hpaulj It's the output of a complicated math function. It's an integer dtype, though.

Comment: We shouldn't have guess as to what's wrong with your "user input", or fish for more details.  I'm voting to close!

Answer (score 1):

The "input" function returns a string. So if you write

```
a = input()
array[a] = 0
```

Then you will have a problem, since a is a string and not an integer as you want. Try casting the input to an int, and see if that fixes the problem.